# .htaccess php_value auto_prepend_file makes 500 error. How can I fix this?

Tags: .htaccess, php

My .htaccess is as follows:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /school
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1

php_value auto_prepend_file ./inc/library.php

ErrorDocument 404 /school/index.php?page=404
```

As of the `./`, I read that indicates a relative path.

Comment: `./` means "a path relative to the current work directory". You are sure, that the file is there, where it is expected to be? Try an absolute path. Also ensure, that the file doesn't produce any errors itself.

Comment: I think I am cgi, but can I make a php.ini in any directory?

Comment: It isn't related to `php.ini` in this case. But no, you can't: The interpreter wont look for it ;)

Comment: I am cgi, so I can't use ht access... I need to set php.ini varibles, but I don't have access to php.ini

Comment: Ah, right, CGI ^^ If you are using `FastCGI` via `php-fpm` (which if its not the case you definitely should consider) you can set the values in the pool-settings http://php.net/install.fpm.configuration#example-60 It is probably also possible to pass values to FastCGI from within Apache, but don't know how, I use Nginx (see the example on the same page). This could also work for the regular CGI SAPI, but I really recommend FastCGI

Comment: Server API CGI/FastCGI

Comment: http://alex.piechowski.org/test/info.php

Answer (score 9):

Note: This information was taken nearly verbatim from [another website](http://support.tigertech.net/php-value), I thought it explained the issue well and I highly suspect this is the problem:

---

#### Using php_flag or php_value in .htaccess files

Some PHP scripts suggest using "php_value" or "php_flag" commands in .htaccess files, as in this example:

```
php_value  include_path         ".:/usr/local/lib/php" 
php_flag   display_errors       Off
php_value  upload_max_filesize  2M
php_value  auto_prepend_file    "./inc/library.php"
```

However, some servers run PHP in "CGI mode" (not as an Apache module), so you can't use "php_value" or "php_flag" commands in .htaccess files. If you try to do so, you'll see an "internal server error" message.

You can modify your php.ini file to get the same effect, though. In fact, modifying php.ini is actually more flexible than using php_value or php_flag: there are many things you can't override using .htaccess files, but you can override almost any PHP setting in the php.ini file.

To get the same effect as the .htaccess lines above, you would simply add these lines to your custom php.ini file:

```
include_path = ".:/usr/local/lib/php" 
display_errors = Off
upload_max_filesize = 2M
auto_prepend_file = "./inc/library.php"
```

Note: Some systems will require quotes around the paths, and some must not use quotes.

Comment: What if I don't have direct access to php.ini?

Comment: Create your own file called `php.ini` and put it in the root directory of your project (note that it may not work if you are on shared hosting). I know you may realize this, but this particular problem is probably better solved with a simple `require "./inc/library.php";` in your PHP script. Almost all PHP applications include common files for every request, I don't recommend htaccess or php.ini for this.

Comment: I figured it might be more efficient if I do it this way.

Comment: You're worrying about efficiency of something that's already efficient, do not continue your programming career that way! Worry about organization and clean code, don't look for bottlenecks that aren't there.

Comment: I meant cleanliness as well. But I guess I'll stick with includes. If you would like, you could make an answer correcting my mistake in wanting to do this, and recommend I use includes and list reasons I wouldn't want to use this method. I'll for sure give you best answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [htscanner](http://pecl.php.net/package/htscanner) PHP module if you want to use `php_value` in your .htaccess files when running php as a CGI/FastCGI application.