# Include a php file in htaccess and run it on other php files

Tags: php, .htaccess

How can I include a php file in htaccess to work on all other php files first?
For example here are the files in my web root:

```
index3.php
index4.php
check.php
folder1
folder2
```

When I execute a php file I would like the `check.php` file to run first.

Comment: You cannot do that with .htaccess files... just put require_once('check.php') as a first statement in index(*).php files

Comment: Add `include(check.php)` at the top of pages index3 & index4?

Comment: well.. you can actually use a .htaccess file to set the php.ini setting [`auto_prepend_file`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) which then runs that specific file before the actual file runs.

Comment: i dont want to use include in php !! i want to use .htaccess .. what should i do with auto_prepend_file?? when i put it in my htaccess i see 500 error !!

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following line to your `.htaccess` file to (automatically) include a file before the requested file runs. Like this:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "file.php"
```

More info at the PHP documentation [auto_prepend_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) and [php_value in htaccess](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php)

Comment: when i add this to my htaccess i see 500 error when i am try to load my website

Comment: are you sure your file.php file does not throw any errors?

Comment: also, just noticed, you should use double quotes (not single) around the path. Forgot :$

Comment: yes i am shure .. there is no error in my php file !

Comment: this is my php source :<br> <?php

$light = '1';

if($light == '1'){

return true;
}

?>

Comment: @user3464859 - Checkout this link for how to use `auto_prepend_file`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885311/htaccess-php-value-auto-prepend-file-makes-500-error-how-can-i-fix-this

Answer (score 0):

You could use sort of a gateway file for this, at the bottom or top of your `check.php` file you add a include directive like:

```
// here you need to check if the file exists and are a valid php file etc
$file = ((isset($_GET['file']) && is_file($_GET['file'])) ? $_GET['file'] : null);
if(is_file($file)):
  // include the file
  include_once($file);
endif;
```

Then in your `.htaccess` file you add something like:

```
// route every request to 'check.php' appending the filename of the request
// of course you also would have to check so the request isn't a folder or invalid
// file like an image css etc
RewriteRule (.*) check.php?file=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I'm not sure how safe the above is but it should work.